# drag and drop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I've a problem with **jquery** drag and drop. I want to  get x,y , when  mouse dropped . My problem is the drop function not executed .

**that is my code**

```
function DragDrop(ar)
{
var a=0;
for(a=0;a<ar.length;a++)
{
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#" + ar[a]).draggable();
$("#" + ar[a]).droppable({
drop: function() { alert('dropped'); }
});
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click View Source on this page

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Notice that draggable and droppable are two different elements

Your code shows both draggable and droppable as being `$("#" + ar[a])`

That is probably what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

in event you will  get event.x and event.y

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something more like this: **[Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/p4tPj/)**

```
function DragDrop(ar) {
    var a = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < ar.length; a++) {
        $("#" + ar[a]).draggable().mouseup(function() {
            var p= $(this).position();
            $('#output').html('x: ' + p.left + ', y: ' + p.top);
        });;
    }
}
```

HTML used in above example

```
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="asdf" ></div>
```